# Continuous complex function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, continuity

I have this function
$$F(z)=\frac{1}{\alpha-i\sqrt{z}}$$ with $\alpha>0$ and the determination of the square root with $\Im z>0$. I have to study its continuity in the set
$$A=\lbrace z|a\leq\Re z\leq b, 0<\Im z\leq 1\rbrace$$
The denominator is zero if $\sqrt{z}=-i\alpha$ so if $z=-\alpha^2$ which is not in $A$, so my function is continuous in $A$, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $F$ is continuous in the open upper half-plane. Here is a geometric way to see this: the  principal branch of the square root maps the upper half-plane onto the positive quadrant. Multiplication by $i$ rotates it to the second quadrant ($x<0$, $y>0$). Thus, the denominator cannot vanish; it even admits a lower bound $|\alpha-i\sqrt{z}|\ge \alpha$, which implies $F$ is both continuous and bounded in the open upper half-plane.